# Localization issue in laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, localization, localhost, laravel-6

I have two domains directing to a single laravel application.

```
test_en.site
test_fr.site
```

**MY REQUIREMENT**

`test_en.site` need to load the English content by default and `test_fr.site` need to load the French content.

(If a user accesses to `test_en.site`, still the user can change the language to French, and if a user accesses to `test_fr.site` user can change the language to English.)

**WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR**

In order to check the domain and load the correct language accordingly, in my Middleware, `Localization.php` I have added the following condition.

app/Http/Middleware/Localization.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App;
use Closure;

class Localization
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (session()->has('locale')) {
            App::setLocale(session()->get('locale'));
            return $next($request);
        }

        // load english by default if the root is test_en.site or else load french for other domains
        else {
            $locale = $request->root() == 'http://test_en.site' ? 'En' : 'Fr';
            App::setLocale($locale);
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**

I created two virtual hosts for the same project with two test domains and tried in my local then it works well...

But when I tested this out on the live server it keeps loading the English for the French domain too.

```
$locale = $request->root() == 'http://test_en.site' ? 'En' : 'Fr';
App::setLocale($locale);
return $next($request)
```

I even tried using the `getHost()` method instead of `root()` but that too works only in the local server...

Where am I doing wrong and How can I fix this, as this code works fine in the local I'm struggling to find the solution...

Comment: Might be easier to work with subdomains, as that has built-in support with Laravel. So that you would instead use `http://en.test.site` and `http://fr.test.site`. Then in Laravel, you can simply use subdomain routing. Would that be viable for your application?

Comment: @Qirel thank you for the comment, but the requirement is to go with two different domains... and the code works well in local server....

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct, I think you forgot to add it into Kernel.php

if it still not work

try this snippet instead

**p/s edited**

```php
        // get subdomain
        $url_array = explode('.', parse_url($request->url(), PHP_URL_HOST));
        $subdomain = $url_array[0]; // in your case it should be test_en/test_fr

        $languages = ['test_en' => 'en', 'test_fr' => 'fr'];

        App::setLocale($languages[$subdomain]);

        return $next($request);
```

Comment: no I have already added it to kernel, \App\Http\Middleware\Localization::class, I'm sorry but I don't understand your code, can you explain a bit please

Answer (score 0):

You can try use https://github.com/movemoveapp/laravel-localization localization package. Your problem describe here https://github.com/movemoveapp/laravel-localization#localization-switch-by-domain-names.

How to use?
In your case you have:

- test_en.site - En version
- test_fr.site - Fr version

Install package and add to `.env` file new environments

```php
LOCALIZATION_DOMAIN_NAME_EN=test_en.site
LOCALIZATION_DOMAIN_NAME_FR=test_fr.site
```

A next step modify your web routes in `routes/web.php`, like to

```php
Route::group([
    'middleware' => [ 'localizationDomainRedirect' ]
], function()
{
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        return View::make('index');
    });
});
```

So, by http://test_en.site/ opened En version, by http://test_fr.site - Fr.

Comment: @Steve fixed. Look at the edited comment.